# XSS inside anchor tag (<a>) without user interaction?

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

Is it possible to inject a payload inside `<a>` tag such that the script runs without user interaction?

The injection is inside the `href` attribute. I can inject `onmouseover` or `onclick` attributes, but user interaction is required.

The `onfocus` and `autofocus` trick does not work in `<a>` tag (correct me if I'm wrong).

In my case, the page cannot be loaded in iframe, so I can't do tricks with iframes.

Do you know some other tricks?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can force the user interaction with CSS, by making the `a` element an fixed positioned block element with a large size and z-index.

`<a style="display: block; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 99999; width: 9999px; height: 9999px;" onmouseover="alert('xss')">`

Comment: `mousemove` would be better in that `mouseover` might not fire on a full-window elm because the pointer is already "over" the elm. (both events should require movement)

Comment: Wouldn't absolute positioning (even if combined with `left: 0; top: 0;`) place the element relative to its offset parent? I think `position: fixed` would do the trick, as it allows for positioning relative to the viewport and not just the closest positioned parent. Perhaps one could even add `right: 0; bottom: 0;`, which would effectively cover the entire page.

Comment: @rhino Yes, sorry, will fix.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, that's possible.**

> The `onfocus` and `autofocus` trick does not work in  tag (correct me if I'm wrong).

Correct, the `autofocus` attribute doesn't exist for `<a>` tags. But instead, you can take advantage of anchor names to still achieve the autofocus effect.

E.g., create a document with this link:

```
<a href="#" onfocus="alert('Gimme bounty!')" name="foo">Click me</a>
```

Now open the document as `https://example.com/anchor.html#foo`. The anchor `#foo` will make the browser autofocus the link element with the name `foo` and trigger the JS payload.

(This works for me in Google Chrome but not Firefox.)

Comment: might try a meta redirect 
 to change the hash after page-load, to see if focus() fires in FF

Answer (score 1):

> The `onfocus` and `autofocus` trick does not work in `<a>` tag (correct me if I'm wrong).

At least now (2024, 7 years after your question), this is wrong.

[`autofocus` is a **global** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus), so it also works on `<a>`:

```
<a href="#" autofocus="true" onfocus="alert('xss')">hello world!</a>
```

Here is a complete HTML file to check this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XSS test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" autofocus="true" onfocus="alert('xss')">hello world!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Without the `autofocus` attribute, this requires user interaction.